# Ruby on Rails Pulling Information From Another Site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a ruby on rails project where I have to make a press page but I don't just want to put the articles in the database (that will take too long) is there anyway that you can pull information from another site and display it on your own site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a broad question.

Depending on whether the web applications that you're getting your data from have APIs or not, you would either use those to retrieve the data or you'd have to web scrape it.

For accessing an API you could use [Net:HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) or [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or similar. For web scraping you'd want to use similar libraries for retrieving the page and some parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse the HTML. In both cases you'd want to store the results in your own database to avoid having to scrape/query API upon every request.

Comment: do you think it is better if I manually put the articles in the db myself or use your method.

Comment: It depends, are there new articles all the time? If it needs to be dynamic and keep up to date with these other resources then use one of the techniques above otherwise you'll forever be copying data manually.